# How to programmatically change button title of split view controller?

Tags: ios

I've got a split view controller. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

A `UISplitViewController` sends `splitViewController:willHideViewController:withBarButtonItem:forPopoverController:` to its delegate when it hides the master view.  You can set the bar button item's title to whatever you want.  You can also save the bar button item (in an instance variable for example) and set its title later.